# Let $X=[0,\infty)$. Construct a sequence of functions $f_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that converges uniformly, but that does not converge in $L^2(X)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Does someone mind checking my proof here? I'm primarily concerned with everything from my definition of the set K and onward. I would appreciate any other feedback as well.

NOTE: I am not educated in measure theory or Lebesgue integration. I have a decent understanding of Riemann integration and that is it. My original proof just shows that $f_n$ is not Cauchy in $L^2(X)$ but I wanted to try a proof by contradiction with an arbitrary $f$.

Define the sequence
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(x+1)}}.$$
First, we show that $f_n\to 0$ uniformly.
$$\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(x+1)}}=\frac{1}{n}\to 0.$$
Now, let $f$ be a Lebegue integrable function on $[0,\infty)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(x+1)}}-f(x)\bigg)^2&=\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{n(x+1)}-\frac{2f(x)}{\sqrt{n(x+1)}}+f^2(x)\bigg)dx\\
&\geq \int_0^{\infty}\bigg(f^2(x)-\frac{2|f(x)|}{\sqrt n}\bigg)dx.
\end{align*}
If we can show that $\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(f^2(x)-\frac{2|f(x)|}{\sqrt n}\bigg)dx>0$, then we will succeed in showing that $f_n$ does not converge in $L^2(X)$. So, we assume that
$$\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(f^2(x)-\frac{2|f(x)|}{\sqrt n}\bigg)dx\leq0.$$
There must then be a set $K=\{x\in [0,\infty)|f^2(x)-\frac{2|f(x)|}{\sqrt n}\leq 0\}$ with positive measure. But then, for all $x\in K$, $f(x)=0$ or $|f(x)|\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt n}$. Since $n$ is arbitrary, however, this inequality forces $f$ to be zero on all of $K$. Thus, $f$ is either zero almost everywhere on $[0,\infty)$, in which case
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(f_n(x)-f(x)\bigg)^2dx&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(x+1)}(x)dx\\
&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\log (R+1)}{n}\\
&=\infty.
\end{align*}
Or, $\int_0^{\infty}\bigg(f^2(x)-\frac{2|f(x)|}{\sqrt n}\bigg)dx>0$, in which case our norm is bounded below by a positive value.

Comment: Looks good to me